# Subsetting multiple matrices of a specified size

Tags: r, loops, matrix

Consider my 20x20 matrix:

```
M1 <- matrix(rnorm(400), nrow=20, ncol=20)
```

What I am trying to do is:

- Subset a 5x5 block of this matrix
- Calculate the median of this 5x5 block
- Replace the middle value of this 5x5 block with that median value
- Rinse and repeat with every 5x5 block in the matrix

So far I have managed to do this for all the columns with a fixed block of rows:

```
x <- 0:20

for (i in seq_along(x)) {
  matrixtest[i] <- median(as.matrix(M1[1:5, (1 + i):(5 + i)]))
  M1[3, 3 + seq_along(x)] <- matrixtest[seq_along(x)]
}
```

However, the problem is I want to also do this going down each row, and I can't figure out a way to do it without manually specifying the rows as I have done below.

```
matrixtest2[i] <- median(as.matrix(M1[2:6, (1 + i):(5 + i)]))
matrixtest3[i] <- median(as.matrix(M1[3:7, (1 + i):(5 + i)]))
matrixtest4[i] <- median(as.matrix(I[4:8, (1 + i):(5 + i)]))


M1[4, 4 + seq_along(x)] <- matrixtest2[seq_along(x)]
M1[5, 5 + seq_along(x)] <- matrixtest3[seq_along(x)]
M1[6, 6 + seq_along(x)] <- matrixtest4[seq_along(x)]
```

This approach is obviously undesirable - any insights on how to do this, either with a `for` loop or `apply` statement would be most appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a double `for` loop.

```
> n <- 5L  ## define block length
> res <- vector('list', (n - 1L)^2)  ## initialize result vector
> for (i in seq_len(nrow(M1) - n + 1) - 1L) {
+   for (j in seq_len(nrow(M1) - n + 1) - 1L) {
+     tmp <- M1[1:n + i, 1:n + j]
+     res[[i + 1L]][[j + 1L]] <- replace(tmp, ceiling(length(tmp)/2), median(tmp))
+   }
+ }
> 
> res[[1]][[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    4    1    4    7
[2,]    5    2    5    9    2
[3,]    1    8    4    3    5
[4,]    9    3    6    5    6
[5,]    4    1    6    8    3
> 
> identical(res[[1]][[1]], replace(M1[1:5, 1:5], 13, median(M1[1:5, 1:5])))
[1] TRUE
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
M1 <- matrix(sample(1:9, 400, replace=TRUE), nrow=20, ncol=20)
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `Map`

```
set.seed(42)
M1 <- matrix(rnorm(400), nrow=20, ncol=20)

Map(\(x){
  Map(\(y){
    m1 <- M1[seq(x, length.out=5), seq(y, length.out=5)]
    m1[3,3] <- median(m1)
    m1
  }, 1:16)}, 
1:16)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]        [,5]
[1,]  1.3709584 -0.3066386  0.2059986 -0.3672346  1.51270701
[2,] -0.5646982 -1.7813084 -0.3610573  0.1852306  0.25792144
[3,]  0.3631284 -0.1719174  0.1852306  0.5818237  0.08844023
[4,]  0.6328626  1.2146747 -0.7267048  1.3997368 -0.12089654
[5,]  0.4042683  1.8951935 -1.3682810 -0.7272921 -1.19432890

[[1]][[2]]
           [,1]       [,2]        [,3]        [,4]       [,5]
[1,] -0.3066386  0.2059986 -0.36723464  1.51270701  1.2009654
[2,] -1.7813084 -0.3610573  0.18523056  0.25792144  1.0447511
[3,] -0.1719174  0.7581632  0.08844023  0.08844023 -1.0032086
[4,]  1.2146747 -0.7267048  1.39973683 -0.12089654  1.8484819
[5,]  1.8951935 -1.3682810 -0.72729206 -1.19432890 -0.6667734

...
```